# How to get a specific md5 hash

Tags: md5

Is there a way for me to change/give a file a specific md5 hash.
What I mean is, for two different files with the exact same md5 hash.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you need 2 different files have exact same hash?

Comment: There are a lot of possible uses, such as attacking a digital signature based on MD5, which is not anymore secure for that purpose...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but that's complex. There are papers on the subject:

http://eprint.iacr.org/2004/199.pdf

Search for "Generating MD5 collisions" on the net.